# Javascript nump.zeros

Tags: javascript

Is there a javascript equivalent to numpy's `zeros`, which returns a multidimensional array filled with the element 0?

Specifically, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
x = js.zeros(3,5)
```

And have `x=[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]`.

Is this possible with a one-liner, or do I have to resort to creating `x` manually and then manually filling and pushing the interior arrays?

Comment: no built-in or 1-liner way to do a 2d array like that, but there is [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) that can do 1d that can effectively 1-line it but it'e EM6

Comment: `Array.from(new Array(3), _ => Array(5).fill(0))`

Comment: note that @zerkms [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is also EM6

Comment: I'm not sure why people are down voting... seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: @CrayonViolent it's ES2015 and it's year 2015 outside, so perfectly acceptable :-)

Comment: @zerkms considering the big fat "*This technology's specification has been finalized, but check the compatibility table for usage and implementation status in various browsers.*" note at the top of them, I would not count these as "perfectly acceptable" but maybe that's just IMO :)

Comment: I'm kind of curious what's wrong with the question myself... anybody care to offer some constructive criticism?

Comment: @CrayonViolent babelize_all_the_things.jpg :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with this moderately readable onliner that uses ES2015 features:

```
let matrix = Array.from(new Array(3), _ => Array(5).fill(0));
```

and as a generalized function

```
let zeros = (w, h, v = 0) => Array.from(new Array(h), _ => Array(w).fill(v));
```

References:

- [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)
- [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: [Not supported by Internet Explorer, Opera or Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility). Also, the earliest listed version of chrome that supports this is v45 and at the time of this writing [the latest stable version of chrome is v44](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.ca/2015/07/stable-channel-update_24.html).

Comment: @TinyGiant https://babeljs.io + https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=false&playground=true&code=let%20zeros%20%3D%20(w%2C%20h%2C%20v%20%3D%200)%20%3D%3E%20Array.from(new%20Array(h)%2C%20_%20%3D%3E%20Array(w).fill(v))%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(zeros(5%2C%203))

Comment: @zerkms I would like to point out that babeljs still  uses `.fill` in the "compatible" version even though it's still got the same limits both I and @TinyGiant pointed out.  Also, it makes no sense to write this "1 liner" and then turn around and run it through something that (fails to) make it compatible.. that sorta defeats the point of making it a 1-liner..

Comment: @Crayon Violent: "it makes no sense to write this "1 liner" and then turn around and run it" --- it makes a lot of sense. It's fine to "compile" code before running. That's what you do when you write C# or Java. "that sorta defeats the point of making it a 1-liner" --- it does not at all. One is free to choose if they build using the modern standards or something from 1990s

Comment: but javascript isn't compiled and this is clearly not what the OP was asking for.  The fact is, `.fill` and `.from` are NOT standards, and they are NOT even cross-browser compatible even for all of the latest major browser versions, let alone the de facto previous versions all web devs currently strive to keep compatibility with.  In truth, no offense, it truly boggles my mind that someone with your rep amount would push an answer like this. This is NOT a solution any real web dev would actually use in the real world any time soon

Comment: @CrayonViolent "The fact is, .fill and .from are NOT standards" --- they are. "it truly boggles my mind that someone with your rep amount would push an answer like this" --- well, sometimes people don't like other people's answers, there are comments and a downvote button to express that. "This is NOT a solution any real web dev would actually use in the real world any time soon" --- facebook uses babel, they are not real web developers, sure.

Comment: show me where facebook has run their code through babel and continues to use `.fill` and/or `.from` and I will show you where to submit a bug report to facebook

Comment: @CrayonViolent I'm sorry, I'm not going to continue that. If you have anything to say about **my answer** - please do so.